# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10.0"

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

This code must validate input data from the findActions() method:

```
try {
    System.out.println(findActions(lookingArea.substring(0, right)));// always printing valid number string
    Integer.parseInt(findActions(lookingArea.substring(0, right)));// checking for number format
}
catch(NumberFormatException exc) {
    System.out.println(exc);
}
```

But I always have `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "*number*"`
that is so strange, because checking with `System.out.println(findActions(lookingArea.substring(0, right)));`,

I get `*number*` like 10.0

Comment: 10.0 is not Integer, Use Double.parseDouble... There are lot of questions on SO with similar problem.

Comment: `10.0` is not an `int`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't expect the `.` character.  If you're sure it can be converted to an `int`, then do one of the following:

1. Eliminate the `".0"` off the end of the string before parsing it, or
2. Call `Double.parseDouble`, and cast the result to `int`.

Quoting the linked Javadocs above:

> The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that
>   the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to
>   indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to
>   indicate a positive value.

Comment: Try to parse this number in double 22.46771397047133$70.67165784537792 still getting the same error in parsing. How to solve the exception?

Comment: @AnandSavjani  Why do you expect a string with a `$` character in it to parse as a `double` correctly?

Comment: I am splitting two different numbers with the $ sign but split function was not working with the $ sign and I solved the issue.

Comment: Is it just me or does it seem like PySpark should be smarter and automatically parse 10.0 as 10?

Answer (score 4):

`10.0` is not an integer number. Instead, you can use:

```
int num = (int) Double.parseDouble(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason could be that your string is too long to convert into Integer type, So you can declare it as Long or Double based on the provided input.

```
Long l = Long.parseLong(str);
```